# Using sklearn in android device

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am currently using sklearn doing machine learning for the sensor data I collected from an android device.

But the thing is I need to do predictions after the model is trained. Since there will be lots of sensor data generated in a very short time, doing predicting in a server or some other machine is my last choice.

Then it comes to me that is there a way I could do sklearn in android? I could think of three solutions:

1. Is it possible to run sklearn in android and just let the sklearn script to do the prediction?
2. If not 1, is it possible for me to use some intermediate library in java (android) to pick up the model I trained in python?
3. If not 1 and 2, is it possible for me to use some other machine learning library that is supported in the android platform?

Comment: The models that scikit-learn produces are fully exposed on the estimator objects, but if you need to run predictions from Java code, you'll need to (1) get the models to that code and (2) reproduce parts of the prediction code. How hard that is depends on the model under consideration. Linear models are easy, SVMs are harder, trees are quite hard.

Comment: Currently I am using the kmean as my clustering method, just getting lazy to implement the method myself since I could not guarantee its correctness and efficiency :D

Comment: For parametric functions, like logistic regression, you can have a python based server train the data and return a vector of parameters back to the phone, and code a predictor function in Java yourself. I'm trying that right now with a Django server using scikit-learn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I work on a project that called [sklearn-porter](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter) which ports trained models to a low level programming language like C, Java and JavaScript. More classifiers and regressors will be added at given time.

Comment: Hello! Is the repo still being maintained? Meaning does the implementation still work?

Comment: aewsome! is it still going on?

Comment: Yes, currently I'm working on the next major release: https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter/tree/release/1.0.0

Comment: hey any update on this?