# How do I deploy a scikit-learn model to android?

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I have a model that implements sklearn's RandomForestClassifier. I have saved the model in a 'pickle' file and I want to deploy it to an android application. 
I've seen that this can be accomplished using a Tensorflow Lite file, and a 'hdf5' file can be converted to the same. However I have no idea how to convert my pickle file to hdf5 and then to tflite.

Do I re-implement Random Forest using Tensorflow? What else can I do to deploy it to android?

I do not want to train my model on android, but use my custom trained model on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sklearn in android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004729/using-sklearn-in-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

You can use m2cgen (Model 2 Code Generator), which is a lightweight library that can provide an easy way to transpile trained statistical models into a native code (Python, C, Java, Go, JavaScript, Visual Basic, C#, PowerShell, R, PHP, Dart, Haskell, Ruby, F#)